# Elapsed Time Event Handler in WPF VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, timer, invalidoperationexception

I'm implementing a timer into my program that starts when a button is pressed. Once the time has elapsed, my intention is to close the program; however, I'm getting an invalid operation exception. I have a different part of my program also using the Close() operation, but even if I remove that from the program, it'll throw the error anyway. How can I make it work properly?

```
Public Class Password
    Public timer1 As System.Timers.Timer = New System.Timers.Timer()
    Public loginAttempts As Integer = 0
    Private myPassword As String = "MPCgso4char"



    Private Sub AcceptButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

        wrongPass.Content = "Incorrect password. Please try again."
        wrongPass.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden

        Select Case passTextBox.Text
            Case = myPassword
                Close()
            Case = ""
                wrongPass.Content = "Please enter a valid password."
                wrongPass.Visibility = Visibility.Visible

            Case <> myPassword
                wrongPass.Visibility = Visibility.Visible

        End Select

    End Sub

    Private Sub DeclineButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        passTitle.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
        AcceptButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
        DeclineButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
        showPass.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
        passTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
        If wrongPass.Visibility = Visibility.Visible Then
            wrongPass.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
        End If

        decBtnClickEvent.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
        timer1.Interval = 1500
        timer1.Enabled = True
        timer1.Start()
        AddHandler timer1.Elapsed, AddressOf TimedEvent

    End Sub

    Private Sub passTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs)
        wrongPass.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
    End Sub

    Private Sub showPass_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    End Sub
    Private Sub TimedEvent(sender As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
        Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Enter(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles passTextBox.KeyDown

        If e.Key = Key.Enter Then
            AcceptButton_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use  `Application.Current.Shutdown()` instead of `Close()`

```
Private Sub TimedEvent(sender As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    Application.Current.Shutdown()
End Sub
```

In addition be sure that your `Public Class Password` is't in another thread.

In this case you can use:

```
Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub() Application.Current.Shutdown() End Sub)
```

Comment: Currently, its only appearance is in Application.xaml at StartupUri. The error I'm getting is: "System.InvalidOperationException:'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.' This exception was originally thrown at this call stack: [External Code] {namespace}.Password.TimedEvent(Object, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) in Password.xaml.vb [External Code] " Also, Application.Current.Shutdown() didn't work. Got the same error.

Comment: It means that the class that contains close operation is instanziate in another thread. Try to use an event from the Password class that fire in the MainWindow and here call Close() or Shutdown()

Comment: or you can try  Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub()
                              Application.Current.Shutdown()
                          End Sub)

Comment: I tried to do it through MainWindow and got a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I created a new instance of Password in MainWindow called newPass and, in the error, it's saying that "newPass was Nothing."

Comment: Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub() Application.Current.Shutdown() End Sub) worked for me though!!

Comment: Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub() Application.Current.Shutdown() End Sub) worked for me though!! that's greats